# Getting data from response body using HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, odata, httpwebrequest

I am having a problem trying to get the response body of a HttpWebResponse. 
I have an application that sends a get request to a server using the below URI.
In postman this URI returns the correct number of rows, but using C sharp I don't get a count but rather all entities in the web service (it seems like it is using another URI, not the one I defined below.).

```
URI: "https://<org>/api/data/v9.0/<entity>/$count"
```

I use this code:

```
 HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(apiURL));
            webReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();


            using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Is the question now understandable ?

Comment: I don't know what this: `string.Format(apiURL)` was meant to become, but try creating a new `Uri()` from the address string instead.